# How do you recognise conditional probabilities?

Tags: probability

Given a standard pack of $52$ playing cards you remove the aces
of hearts, diamonds and clubs.

You pick a card at random. Consider the probabilities of getting an ace, and of
getting a spade. Write down the $2\times 2$ probability table for all combinations of these outcomes. Include the total probabilities for each row and column.

Here is the answer:
$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 & \overbrace{{\color{#180}{\mathrm{Ace}}}}^{P(\text{Ace})=\cfrac{1}{49}} &   \overbrace{\color{red}{\mathrm{Not}\space \mathrm{Ace}}}^{P(\text{Not Ace})=\cfrac{48}{49}} \\
 \hline
P(\text{Spade})=\cfrac{13}{49}
\begin{cases}
 &  \\
 & 
\end{cases}{\color{#180}{\mathrm{Spade}}} & \color{#F80}{\cfrac{1}{49}} & \color{blue}{\cfrac{12}{49}}  \\
P(\text{Not Spade})=\cfrac{36}{49}
\begin{cases}
 &  \\
 & 
\end{cases}{\color{red}{\mathrm{Not}\space \mathrm{Spade}}} & \Large\color{blue}{0} & \color{blue}{\cfrac{36}{49}}  \\
\end{array}
$$

$$$$

I understand intuitively why this table is correct. What I'm trying to do is reproduce mathematically the $\color{blue}{\mathrm{blue}}$ probabilities in the table, so I pick one (the $\color{#F80}{\mathrm{orange}}$ one) and try to reproduce $\color{#F80}{\cfrac{1}{49}}$ as follows:

$$\color{#F80}{P(\text{Ace}\mid\text{Spade})=\frac{P(\text{Spade and Ace})}{P(\text{Spade})}=\frac{\frac{1}{49}\times \frac{13}{49}}{\frac{13}{49}}=\frac{1}{49}}\tag{1}$$

$${P(\text{Spade}\mid\text{Ace})=\frac{P(\text{Spade and Ace})}{P(\text{Ace})}=\frac{\frac{1}{49}\times \frac{13}{49}}{\frac{1}{49}}=\frac{13}{49}}\tag{2}$$

$${P(\text{Spade}\mid\text{Ace})=\frac{P(\text{Ace}\mid\text{Spade})P(\text{Spade})}{P(\text{Ace})}=\frac{\frac{1}{49}\times \frac{13}{49}}{\frac{1}{49}}=\frac{13}{49}}\tag{3}$$

$$\color{#F80}{P(\text{Ace}\mid\text{Spade})=\frac{P(\text{Spade}\mid\text{Ace})P(\text{Ace})}{P(\text{Spade})}=\frac{\frac{1}{49}\times \frac{1}{49}}{\frac{1}{49}}=\frac{1}{49}}\tag{4}$$

Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ are the formulae for Conditional probability while $(3)$ and $(4)$ are Baye's theorem.

Finally, my question is as follows:

Why is it that only Equations $(1)$ and $(4)$ give the correct result?

Probabilities and Distribution theory is not my strong point and I cannot understand why all four equations **don't** give the correct answer of $\color{#F80}{\cfrac{1}{49}}$?

Why does it have to be 'Ace given Spade' instead of 'Spade given Ace'?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at $(1)$ I think it's incorrect. Spade and Ace aren't independent outcomes. Isn't it rather true that: $P(Ace \ | \ Spade) = \frac{1/49}{13/49}=\frac{1}{13}$? Yes, it is. The table at the top doesn't represent the conditional probabilities, but the "AND" probabilities.

Comment: And $P(Spade|Ace)=1$.  Bayes' Theorem says $$P(X|Y)=\frac {P(Y|X)P(X)}{P(Y)}$$

Comment: @lulu Thanks for your reply, do you have any idea how to calculate the values marked blue and orange in the table?

Comment: @Iwanttomakegames I'm afraid I still have no idea, like I said, I am completely new to this, all I do know is those are the correct probabilities (from an answer sheet, conditional or otherwise) in the table marked blue and orange. I would like someone to show me mathematically how to calculate them. What is an AND probability? Are you saying conditional probability is only for dependent outcomes?

Comment: Sure, as @Iwanttomakegames remarks that table is computing the joint probabilities, ie the probabilities that both events in question occur.  For the orange one, say, we are asking for the probability that your card is simultaneously an Ace and a Spade, for which the probability is clearly $\frac 1{49}$.  In general, $P(X\cap Y)=P(X|Y)P(Y)=P(Y|X)P(X)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(\text{Ace and Spade})={P(\text{Ace}\mid\text{Spade})}\times P(\text{Spade})=\frac{1}{13}\times \frac{13}{49}=\frac{1}{49}$$

$$P(\text{Spade and Ace})={P(\text{Spade}\mid\text{Ace})}\times P(\text{Ace})=1\times \frac{1}{49}=\frac{1}{49}$$

---

$$P(\text{Not Ace and Spade})={P(\text{Not Ace}\mid\text{Spade})}\times P(\text{Spade})=\frac{12}{13}\times \frac{13}{49}=\frac{12}{49}$$

$$P(\text{Spade and Not Ace})={P(\text{Spade}\mid\text{Not Ace})}\times P(\text{Not Ace})=\frac{12}{48}\times \frac{48}{49}=\frac{12}{49}$$

---

$$P(\text{Not Ace and Not Spade})={P(\text{Not Ace}\mid\text{Not Spade})}\times P(\text{Not Spade})=1\times \frac{36}{49}=\frac{36}{49}$$

$$P(\text{Not Spade and Not Ace})={P(\text{Not Spade}\mid\text{Not Ace})}\times P(\text{Not Ace})=\frac{36}{48}\times \frac{48}{49}=\frac{36}{49}$$

---